# Archive users with FOSUserBunde

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have to archive my users. I added a column to User entity to set them as archived. But I run into some problems with this approach. I have usernames that can be the same between archived users and not archived users, and the same goes with emails. 
1st question : How can I prevent Unique Constraint violation errors with emails and usernames ?
2nd question : How can I do to make FOS check only not archived users in its functions ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can add prefix to name and email of archived users. Ex:
   `archived.%id%.`. Or move them to another table.
2. Extend `UserManager` class and rewrite methods that select users.

   ```
   namespace MyFOSUserBundle;

   class UserManager extends \FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager
   {
       public function findUserBy(array $criteria)
       {
           $criteria['archived'] = 0;
           return $this->getRepository()->findOneBy($criteria);
       }

       public function findUsers()
       {
           return $this->getRepository()->findBy(array('archived' => 0));
       }
   }
   ```

   Set this class as `UserManager` in `FOSUserBundle` parameters:

   ```
   services:
       my_fos_user.user_manager:
           class: MyFOSUserBundle\UserManager
           arguments:
               - "@fos_user.util.password_updater"
               - "@fos_user.util.canonical_fields_updater"
               - "@fos_user.object_manager"
               - "%fos_user.model.user.class%"

   fos_user:
       service:
           user_manager: my_fos_user.user_manager
   ```